# Javascript createImageData() returns 0's

Tags: javascript, canvas

I try to create a canvas (which is a copy of an image) in order to get an array of his RGBA values.
What am I doing wrong?
Help would be appreciated.

```
getColorArray(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var file = this.$el.querySelector("#image-preview-image");
        ctx.drawImage(file, 10, 10);
        
        const imageData = ctx.createImageData(10, 10);
        console.log(imageData);  
    }
```

Comment: You gave the image a 10x10 offset, and you are only extracting the image data from said offset; so of course, it would be blank.

Comment: @skara9 Same thing happens with this code: 
` var x = file.naturalWidth; var y = file.naturalHeight; ctx.drawImage(file, x, y); const imageData = ctx.createImageData(x, y);`

Comment: Why are you setting the offset x and y as the image dimensions?

Comment: @skara9 my bad, fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createImageData()` will just create a new array of color points where all the values are 0. You need to use [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) to get the data that is already on the canvas.

```js
const getColorArray = () => {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var file = document.querySelector("#image-preview-image");
  ctx.drawImage(file, 0, 0);

  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100);
  console.log(imageData);
};

getColorArray();
```

```html
<p>Image:
  <img id="image-preview-image" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIj4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI1MCUiIGN5PSI1MCUiIHI9IjUwJSIgZmlsbD0iZ3JlZW4iIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPgo=" />
</p>
<p>Canvas:
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</p>
```

Comment: This is it, I confused createImageData() and getImageData(). 
Thank you!